# Adding transparency on small numbers/letters with OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on overlapping some digits at the moment and I'm unsure of how to get rid of their white background so that I can overlay the numbers while still showing their whole character.

img1: [image: image1]

img2: [image]

(they're tiny letter pictures, not text)

background: [image]

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('img1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.png')

croppedbg = cv2.imread('background.png')

characters = [img1, img2]

movinginterval = [10, 45]

height, width = croppedbg.shape[:2]
rheight = round(height - (height / 3) * 2)

times = 0

newres = np.array([])


for i in movinginterval:
    iterbg = croppedbg.copy()
    fullcharwidths = sum([t.shape[1] for t in characters])+i
    bgxsplitter = (iterbg.shape[1] - fullcharwidths*2)/(len(characters))
    for t in characters:

        x_offset = round(fullcharwidths + (bgxsplitter*(times)))
        y_offset = rheight

        y1, y2 = y_offset, y_offset + t.shape[0]
        x1, x2 = x_offset, x_offset + t.shape[1]

        alpha_s = t[:, :, 2] / 255.0
        alpha_l = 1.0 - alpha_s

        for c in range(3):
            iterbg[y1:y2, x1:x2, c] = (alpha_s * t[:, :, c] + alpha_l * iterbg[y1:y2, x1:x2, c])

        times += 1 #decreases width interval difference between characters

    try:
        newres = np.concatenate((newres, iterbg), axis=0) #vertically stack both images
    except ValueError:
        newres = iterbg.copy()


plt.imshow(newres)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The top two numbers are working fine, but pushing them closer together as is for the bottom two numbers leads their backgrounds to overlap and cut off the other digits.

I'd like the 0 and the 4 to be distinguishable by making their backgrounds disappear, while the characters remain overlapping for the bottom two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the background by setting the background pixels to `0`. This is like having an alpha of zero on the background. This way when two digits overlap, one digit's background does not mess with another.

I added these two lines:

```
img1[img1[:,:,0]==croppedbg.mean(),:]=0
img2[img2[:,:,0]==croppedbg.mean(),:]=0
```

before the line `characters = [img1, img2]`.

I get this result:

[image]

The pink pixels are because on uploading the images to imgur, their compression changed some values in the original image.

Comment: Any idea on how I can get rid of the extra noise this produces, ie the pink and green dots? I'm having them show up on my images but I'd like to reduce them if possible.

Comment: you shouldn't have the same problem as I had because you will be using the original images in your dataset, not copies downloaded from imgur. Try it out and let me know if you see the same issues.

Comment: I'm having the same issues, it doesn't seem to be due to imgur.

Comment: The modification does not introduce any noise in images. Please try this: `img1[img1[:,:,0]==croppedbg.mean(),:]=0
img2[img2[:,:,0]==croppedbg.mean(),:]=0`

Comment: That's much better, you should edit that into the original post. Thanks a bunch :)